# Codeigniter - Forms with multiple dropzones for Picture Gallery & PDF files

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

Hi I'm working on a real estate project. I have a form which has some inputs & then 3 forms incorporated in the 1st form which have the dropzone class for a simple picture, a picture gallery & pdf files. I tried a lot of techniques but couldn't get the dropzones to work with the main form.

My Issues:

1. Dropzone sends the inputs & picture before submit button gets hit.
2. If after that, the submit button gets clicked then some inputs get null & 2 records get inserted.
3. If I remove or hide the submit button or change it to anchor tag for redirecting then the picture doesn't get uploaded.

Listings_controller:

```
function insert_listing(){
        $pass = rand(0,999);
        $data_seller = array(
            'name'      =>  $this->input->post('name'),
            'email'     =>  $this->input->post('email'),
            'cell'      =>  $this->input->post('cell'),
            'sms'       =>  $this->input->post('sms'),
            'pass'      =>  MD5($pass),
            'status'    =>  'seller',
            'last_date' =>  date('Y-m-d')
        );
        $result1 = $this->users_model->add_seller($data_seller);

        $data_listing = array(
            'code'      =>  $this->input->post('code'),
            'address'   =>  $this->input->post('address'),
            'city'      =>  $this->input->post('city'),
            'state'     =>  $this->input->post('state'),
            'zipcode'   =>  $this->input->post('zipcode'),
            'process'   =>  $this->input->post('process'),
            'step'      =>  $this->input->post('step'),
            'price'     =>  $this->input->post('price'),
            'agent_id'  =>  $this->input->post('agent'),
            'seller_id' =>  $this->db->insert_id()
        );
        $result2 = $this->listings_model->add_listing($data_listing);

        if($result2){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Listing Added Successfully');
        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Listing Already Exists !');
        }

        //Dropzone - Pic
        if(!empty($_FILES)){
            $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            $fileName = substr(sha1(rand(000,9999)),0,7).$_FILES['file']['name'];
            $targetPath = getcwd().'/assets/admin/images/image-gallery/';
            $targetFile = $targetPath.$fileName;
            move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

            $listing_id = $result2['id'];
            $data_listing_pic['listing_id'] = $listing_id;
            $data_listing_pic['pic'] = $fileName;
            $result3 = $this->listings_model->add_listing_pic($data_listing_pic);
        }
        redirect('admin/listings');
    }
```

Users_model:

```
    //Seller Add
    function add_seller($data_seller){
        //Check Duplicate
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->where('email',$data_seller['email']);

        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            $seller_id = $query->result_array();
            $data_seller['id'] = $seller_id[0]['id'];
            //Update Info
            $this->db->where('email',$data_seller['email']);
            $this->db->update($this->table,$data_seller);
            return $data_seller;
        }else{
            //INSERT Seller
            $result = $this->db->insert($this->table,$data_seller);
            //GET Last Inserted ID
            $seller_id = $this->db->insert_id();
            $data_seller['id'] = $seller_id;
            return $data_seller;
        }
    }
```

Listings_model:

```
        //Listing Add
        function add_listing($data_listing){
            $result = $this->db->insert($this->table,$data_listing);
            $listing_id = $this->db->insert_id();
            $data_listing['id'] = $listing_id;
            return $data_listing;
        }

        //Listing Pic Add
        function add_listing_pic($data_listing_pic){
            $result = $this->db->insert($this->pics_table,$data_listing_pic);
        return $result;
    }
```

My View:

```
   <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/insert_listing" class="dropzone dz-clickable" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="code" value="<?php echo $listing_code; ?>" />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <strong>Property Information:</strong>
                <br><br>
                <div class="form-group form-float form-group-lg">
                    <div class="form-line">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" autofocus required />
                        <label class="form-label">Street Address:</label>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-line">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" required />
                        <label class="form-label">City/Town:</label>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-line">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="state" required />
                        <label class="form-label">State:</label>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-line">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="zipcode" required />
                        <label class="form-label">Zip Code:</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <strong>Seller Information:</strong>
                <br><br>
                <div class="form-group form-float form-group-lg">
                    <div class="form-line">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required />
                        <label class="form-label">Full Name(s):</label>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-line">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" required />
                        <label class="form-label">Seller's Email:</label>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-line">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cell" required />
                        <label class="form-label">Cell Phone Number:</label>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="demo-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="md_checkbox_26" name="sms" class="filled-in chk-col-blue" checked />
                        <label for="md_checkbox_26">Send status updates via SMS</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <strong>Listing Agent:</strong>
                <br /><br />
                <select class="form-control show-tick" name="agent" required >
                    <option value="">-- Please choose from the drop down --</option>
                    <?php for($j=0; $j < count($agent_list); $j++){ ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $agent_list[$j]['id']; ?>" ><?php echo $agent_list[$j]['name']; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
                <br />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <strong>Listing Status Information:</strong>
                <br /><br />
                <select class="form-control show-tick" name="process" required >
                    <option value="">-- Please choose from the drop down --</option>
                    <option value="Listing Process">Listing Process</option>
                </select>
                <br /><br />
                <select class="form-control show-tick" name="step" required >
                    <option value="">-- Please choose from the drop down --</option>
                    <option value="1">Step 1: The Prep</option>
                    <option value="2">Step 2: File Set Up</option>
                    <option value="3">Step 3: Pre-listing Checklists</option>
                    <option value="4">Step 4: Sign Installation</option>
                    <option value="5">Step 5: Feature Sheets</option>
                    <option value="6">Step 6: Open Houses</option>
                    <option value="7">Step 7: You Received an Offer!</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <strong>Photo and Price:</strong>
                <br><br>
                <div class="form-group form-float form-group-lg">
                    <div class="form-line">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price" required />
                        <label class="form-label">Listing Price: $</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/insert_listing_pdf" id="PDFUpload" class="dropzone dz-clickable" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="dz-message">
                        <div class="drag-icon-cph">
                            <i class="material-icons">touch_app</i>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Drop the Photo here or Click to Upload.</h3>
                        <em>(It is recommended to upload the most attractive photo that will catch the user's eye)</em>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <strong>Upload Gallery Photos:</strong>
                <br><br>
                <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/insert_listing_gallery" id="GalleryUpload" class="dropzone dz-clickable" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="dz-message">
                        <div class="drag-icon-cph">
                            <i class="material-icons">touch_app</i>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Drop files here or click to upload.</h3>
                        <em>(Upload all the gallery photos of the property in this section)</em>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <strong>Upload PDF Files:</strong>
                <br><br>
                <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/insert_listing_pdf" id="PDFUpload" class="dropzone dz-clickable" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="dz-message">
                        <div class="drag-icon-cph">
                            <i class="material-icons">touch_app</i>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Drop files here or click to upload.</h3>
                        <em>(Upload all the PDF files related to the property in this section)</em>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg waves-effect">ADD LISTING</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: MD5 is not sufficient for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead.

Comment: I found [this article from 2013](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Combine-normal-form-with-Dropzone) on how to submit your form with dropzone and normal form fields. Hopefully dropzone's config hasn't changed that much.

Comment: @ourmandave - I tried that but the dropzone doesn't even work from the example